# SQL: Multiple DESCRIBE statement single script output?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, multiple-tables

I'm in a academic situation in which I have to use the `describe` command for generating script output based on multiple tables. Is there any way to manipulate the output to describe multiple tables together, similar to how query output tables can be manipulated?

*I would imagine creating a view in which the tables are looped over? I'm not that advanced in PL/SQL yet, though.*

Comment: Are you just wanting column name and datatype?

Comment: Describe is a client command and isn't flexible, or something you can refer to from SQL or PL/SQL. Are you sure you're restricted to that, and can't query the data dictionary directly? Or use the built-in packages?

Comment: Yes, the restriction is for spooling results from multiple tables "using the describe command." It's at the very beginning of a PL/SQL course. I felt boxed in but wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: you could create a (client-side) script that consists of a sequence of `describe <table_name>` commands this list being enclosed by `spool <file>` and `spool off` instructions.